# pyspark - Dynamically select column content based on other column from the same row

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

my data frame looks like:

---

| categoryName | catA | catB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| catA | 0.25 | 0.75 |
| catB | 0.5 | 0.5 |

Where categoryName has String type, and cat* are Double. I would like to add column that will contain value from column which name is in the categoryName column:

---

| categoryName | catA | catB | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| catA | 0.25 | 0.75 | 0.25 |
| catB | 0.5 | 0.7 | 0.7 |

in the first row 'score' has value from column name 'catA'
in the second row 'score' value from column name 'catB'
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to create a map out of column names and values for each row, and then access the map with the value defined in a desired column.

What's cool about this is that it can work for as many columns as you want.

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [
    {"categoryName": "catA", "catA": 0.25, "catB": 0.75},
    {"categoryName": "catB", "catA": 0.5, "catB": 0.7},
]

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "map", F.expr("map(" + ",".join([f"'{c}', {c}" for c in df.columns]) + ")")
    )
    .withColumn("score", F.expr("map[categoryName]"))
    .drop("map")
)
```

Result:

```
+----+----+------------+-----+                                                  
|catA|catB|categoryName|score|
+----+----+------------+-----+
|0.25|0.75|catA        |0.25 |
|0.5 |0.7 |catB        |0.7  |
+----+----+------------+-----+
```